# Haystack, SearchQuerySet().filter is not returning anything. ( django + elastic search)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, searchqueryset

my code looks like following. here SearchQuerySet().filer is not returning anything.

> search_indexes.py

```
class sample_index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    books = indexes.CharField(model_attr='books')
    search_tags = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepere_tags(self, obj):
        return [tag.tag for tag in obj.seacrh_tags.all()]

    def get_model(self):
        return sample

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects

    def load_all_queryset(self):
        return sample.objects.all().select_related()
```

> ```
> model.py
> ```

```
class tags(models.Model):    
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.tag)

class sample(models.Model):

books = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=256, null=False)
search_tags = models.ManyToManyField(tags, db_index=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.md5sum)
```

> view.py

```
def search_h(request):

    search_string = request.GET.get('search_string', '')
    values = []

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(search_tags=search_string)

    values = [a.object for a in sqs[0:10]]

    return render(request, "search/indexes/app/test.html", {'values': values})
```

> sample_text.txt

```
{{ object.text }}
{% for tag in object.search_tags.all %}
{{ tag.tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here values is a empty list. even sqs is coming as empty. Any idea what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined following field in index `search_tags = indexes.MultiValueField()`. But you are preparing a MultiValueField `tags` (`prepare_tags`) which does not exist in index, it should be `prepare_search_tags`:

`def prepare_search_tags(self, obj):
       return [tag.tag for tag in obj.seacrh_tags.all()]`

Comment: Thanks Aamir, I made that change, even after that.. this field is not getting indexed.

Comment: Have you done `rebuild_index` and `update_index` after the changes?

Comment: ok last guess try to filter using `__in` lookup as `SearchQuerySet().filter(search_tags__in=search_string)`

Comment: No luck, tags are not there in the index it self.

Comment: are just tags are not in index or there is nothing being indexed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74928/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-tanuj).